# Changing layer name of output vector from processing script in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2.4, qgis-processing

I define an input csv file and an output like so in my processing script:

```
##Input_CSV_File=file
##Output_Shapefile=output vector
```

The output shapefile is added to the map automatically when the script is done, but the name of the layer in QGIS  is always "Output Shapefile".  I want to name the layer based on something in the file.  Is there a way to change the name the layer is added with after the script is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processing offers two approaches:

- using the file name or
- using the output name specified in the scripts.

You can change the behavior in the Processing options:

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to be able to set the name myself so if I give this script to someone it would work for them without any setup, but taking the name from the filename will work.  Thanks.