# Changing display name of layer with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, layers

I did a batch processing of several vector layers and now the display name for every file is "dissolved" when accessing the `layer.name()` function in QGIS. I [read in this answer from underdark](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140135/can-you-change-the-layer-name-of-an-output-vector-from-a-processing-script-in-qg) to [Changing layer name of output vector from processing script in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140135), that I can set the name to the file name but unfortunaly too late.

I am able to get all the files in my project to be in a list with

```
layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
```

and all the names with this:

```
names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()]
```

With the help of [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34560/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-a-project-or-layer-file-in-pyqgis) to [Getting path of project, or layer file in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34560), I can get the names of the file I am working with:

```
import os 
real_names = []
for li in layers:
   (myDirectory,nameFile) = os.path.split(li.dataProvider().dataSourceUri())
   real_names.append(nameFile.split("|")[0]
```

Reading the [API docu for the QgsVectorLayer](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsVectorLayer.html) didnt helped me.
What I  want  is to rename the files to show the filename as display name. How to archive that with the python console?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use something like the following to rename all layers to their respective filename (excluding the extension):

```
import os

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer.source()))[0]
    layer.setLayerName(basename)
```